# Is it possible to catch netty exception in Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

It seems to me that netty has its own exception handlers and they don't propagate exceptions (ie. IOException) back to camel route. Is there any way to know that client has disconnected?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.
My problem was releasing clients that would just wait forever to get some kind of response from netty mostly in case of connections closed by remote hosts during processing the pipeline.

What needs to be done is to add a custom handler to the pipeline that should extend `ChannelDuplexHandler` and override `connect` and write `methods` or `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` and override `channelInactive`. I used `ChannelDuplexHandler`.

```
public class ExceptionHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

private final NettyProducer producer;

@Override
public void connect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress,
                    ChannelPromise promise)
        throws Exception {
    ctx.connect(remoteAddress, localAddress, promise)
            .addListener((future -> {
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    // no need to do anything here, camel will manage it on its own
                }
            }));
}

@Override
public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
    ctx.write(msg, promise).addListener(future -> {
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            reportStatusBackToCamel(ctx);
        }
    });
}

private void reportStatusBackToCamel(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    NettyCamelState nettyCamelState = producer.getCorrelationManager().getState(ctx, ctx.channel(),
            new IOException());
    Exchange exchange = nettyCamelState.getExchange();
    AsyncCallback callback = nettyCamelState.getCallback();
    exchange.setException(new RuntimeException("Client disconnected"));
    callback.done(false);
    }
}
```

In case of `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` just put exchange handling into `channelInactive` method.

In your `ClientInitializerFactory` in `initChannel` you add this handler to the pipeline:

```
 pipeline.addLast(new ExceptionHandler(producer));
```

`producer` is given to you on application startup. If you need additional spring injected beans as I did, you simply end up having a couple of constructors in your factory class, one `@Autowired` (with your injected fields) calling the other setting additional producer field.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. I'm having the same issue, where Netty handles an exception itself instead of propagating back to my Camel route (which worked fine with mina in the same setup). I've tried your approach, but I can't get the **if (!future.isSuccess())** from write to trigger on disconnect. Setup is route 1 -> route 2 (netty producer) -> route 3 (throw new CamelExchangeException), where route 1 and 2 are within the same RouteBuilder, and route 3 is simulating a host, in which an exception gets thrown on certain criteria for testing purposes. Any ideas to this? Thanks!