# Apache Camel - Netty Exception to log at route builder

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am new to apache Camel and netty. I have a requirement that if a socket that is connected to the netty server disconnects, I need to log that. In apache camel route builder, I didn't get any way to get back these exceptions like IOException, connection reset by peer. I tried the suggestion from these links

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940482/how-can-i-detect-network-disconnection-in-apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829251/is-it-possible-to-catch-netty-exception-in-camel)

[Is it possible to catch netty exception in Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829251/is-it-possible-to-catch-netty-exception-in-camel)

but was not able to get it done. If there is some way of getting netty server exception at camel route builder level? Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default Camel error handler is scoped within boundaries of exchange, i.e. from the moment consumer creates an exchange to its destruction.

In order to expand scope of error handler you need to bridge consumer and error handler.

You need to create Endpoint and provide property key "bridgeErrorHandler".

```
 NettyEndpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint("mynetty", NettyEndpoint.class);
 endpoint.setBridgeErrorHandler(true);
 // set other endpoint properties
```

Further

```
from("ref:mynetty).
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me getting the exception at route builder level.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to define the clientInitializerFactory?
if you using the clientInitializerFactory you need to add the handle manually e.g encoder/decoder and etc..

if only about logging, you just need to log when the connection is disconnected (channelInactive).

```
public class NettyProducerTest extends RouteBuilder {

    public CamelContext CamelContext;

    public NettyProducerTest(CamelContext context) {
        this.CamelContext = context;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        NettyProducerTest test = new NettyProducerTest(context);
        context.addRoutes(test);

        context.start();
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
        context.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        final org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry registry = new org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry();
        final org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry compositeRegistry = new org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry();

        compositeRegistry.addRegistry(this.CamelContext.getRegistry());
        compositeRegistry.addRegistry(registry);
        ((org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext) this.CamelContext).setRegistry(compositeRegistry);
        registry.put("cipf", new NettyProducerTest.CustomChannelPipelineFactory(null));

        from("stream:in?promptMessage=Enter Msg: ").log("message: ${body}")
                .to("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:9999?textline=true&sync=true&clientInitializerFactory=#cipf")
                .log("response: ${body}");

    }

    public class CustomChannelPipelineFactory extends ClientInitializerFactory {

        private NettyProducer producer;

        public CustomChannelPipelineFactory(NettyProducer producer) {
            this.producer = producer;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientInitializerFactory createPipelineFactory(NettyProducer producer) {
            return new CustomChannelPipelineFactory(producer);
        }

        @Override
        protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = ch.pipeline();
            channelPipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            channelPipeline.addLast("delimeter", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(1000));
            channelPipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            channelPipeline.addLast("handler", new CustomChannelHandler(producer));
        }
    }

    public class CustomChannelHandler extends ClientChannelHandler {

        private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomChannelHandler.class);

        public CustomChannelHandler(NettyProducer producer) {
            super(producer);
        }

        @Override
        public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            super.channelInactive(ctx);
            LOG.info("disconnected");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou @chiochuan , I tried using this and it seems that message is not getting propogated to camel processor after adding this. Then on the same line, I tried ServerChannelHandler which seems to be working. Is it correct to use ServerChannelHandler? Do you have any link where I could find more details regarding this. As i am not much aware of all these handlers.

Comment: you are doing camel netty as producer or consumer? above code is assuming that is producer(client). if you are using netty as consumer(server), you can change the extends ServerInitializerFactory and ServerChannelHandler. you can refer to netty documentation for more detail, https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html

Comment: Thanks @Chiochuan.  I am using netty as consumer(Server).